# MacOS: не могу переименовать файл

Tags: macos, mac

Мне надо сделать все по этой [инструкции](https://outluch.wixsite.com/rmbp-crash) (такие же симптомы в ноута)

Целостность системы отключил, но все равно не могу переименовать файл, говорит

```
mv: rename /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext to /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext.BAK: Read-only file system
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Изменить права доступа к файлу

Comment: через `sudo chmod`

Comment: chmod: Unable to change file mode on /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext: Read-only file system

Comment: Перезагружались после отключения проверки ?

Comment: Вообще не знаю как сейчас, на старых макось я перетягивал кекст на рабочий стол, выполнял с ним необходимые манипуляции и кидал обратно с заменой

Comment: мне его удалить надо